# しかし used as filler

Tags: grammar, translation

Can しかし be used as a filler word in certain contexts? In a script I'm translating, a character says:

> しかし嬉しいな。昔考えてた演出を、ここでできるなんてね。

His previous line is about a stage direction, so it has nothing to do with anything anyone said before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This しかし is not a pure filler like "um", but is a conjunction similar to それにしても, それはそうと, or "anyway" used when changing topics.

From 明鏡国語辞典:

> #### しかし
>
> ❷前の話題からそれることを述べ始めるときに使う。「しかし今日は暑いですね」「企画は順調です。しかしお茶はまだかな」

From デジタル大辞泉:

> #### [しかし](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%97%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97/#jn-94403)
>
> 2. 今まで述べてきた事柄を受けて、話題を転じるときに用いる。それはともかく。それはそれとして。「よく思い切って会社をやめたね。―これからどうするつもりなの」
> 3. 感情をこめて言いはじめるときに用いる。それにしても。なんとまあ。「―よくこんなりっぱな家を建てたものだ」